# How to count selected word in 2D table

Tags: python, psutil

I want to print disk information with psutil like this:

```
Device:  C:\
Mountpoint:  C:\
File system type:  NTFS
Permissions that disk:  rw,fixed
```

How do you write it so that it prints as many disks as there are on your computer?

For example:

```
print('Device: ', psutil.disk_partitions()[0][0])
print('Mountpoint: ', psutil.disk_partitions()[0][1])
print('File system type: ', psutil.disk_partitions()[0][2])
print('Permissions that disk: ', psutil.disk_partitions()[0][3])
```

If I write 
`print(psutil.disk_partitions())` it prints:

```
[sdiskpart(device='C:\\', mountpoint='C:\\', fstype='NTFS', opts='rw,fixed'), sdiskpart(device='D:\\', mountpoint='D:\\', fstype='CDFS', opts='ro,cdrom'), sdiskpart(device='E:\\', mountpoint='E:\\', fstype='NTFS', opts='rw,fixed'), sdiskpart(device='F:\\', mountpoint='F:\\', fstype='NTFS', opts='rw,fixed')]`
```

So how I can do that? I'm a beginner in programming.  I thought about counting 'sdiskpart' and printing information on that basis (for example if are 3 disks it prints from psutil  psutil.disk_partitions([0]) to psutil.disk_partitions([2]))

Answer (score 0):

`disk_partitions()` returns a list of partitions, you can loop over it, and print the desired attributes.

```
for partition in psutil.disk_partitions():
    print('Device: ', partition.device)
    print('Mountpoint: ', partition.mountpoint)
    print('File system type: ', partition.fstype)
    print('Permissions that disk: ', partition.opts)
```

Comment: Okay it works, thanks a lot of. Maybe you have an idea how can I do it so that it shows: first disk, second disk, etc. too?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. You can simply increment a counter variable so you can display `'Disk #' + counter`. This is really basic stuff any programmer should know how to do.